# Combining consecutive dates into ranges

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a List of objects

```
public class sample
{
 public DateTime Date;
 public string content;
}
```

I want to be able to create a list of new objects

```
public class sampleWithIntervals
{
 public DateTime startDate;
 public DateTime endDate;
 public string content;
}
```

The sample objects should be grouped into intervals based on the content. The intervals can include only those dates that are included in the original sample list.
I dont know how to do this in Linq.

Sample data:

```
{"10/1/2013", "x"}
{"10/2/2013", "x"}
{"10/2/2013", "y"}
{"10/3/2013", "x"}
{"10/3/2013", "y"}
{"10/10/2013", "x"}
{"10/11/2013", "x"}
{"10/15/2013", "y"}
{"10/16/2013", "y"}
{"10/20/2013", "y"}

This should give me 
{"10/1/2013","10/3/2013", "x"}
{"10/2/2013","10/3/2013", "y"}
{"10/10/2013","10/11/2013", "x"}
{"10/15/2013","10/16/2013", "y"}
{"10/20/2013","10/20/2013", "y"}
```

Comment: What if the consecutive range has both x and y? Should they then be in two groups?

Comment: Does it have to be in Linq?  A simple loop will be _much_ cleaner.

Comment: Loop is also fine. and yes they should be in two different groups

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a non-Linq way to do it:

```
List<sampleWithIntervals> groups = new List<sampleWithIntervals>();  
sampleWithIntervals curGroup = null;

foreach(sample s in samples.OrderBy(sa => sa.content).ThenBy(sa => sa.Date))
{
    if(curGroup == null || // first group
        s.Date != curGroup.endDate.AddDays(1) ||
        s.content != curGroup.content   // new group
      ) 
    {
        curGroup = new sampleWithIntervals() {startDate = s.Date, endDate = s.Date, content = s.content};
        groups.Add(curGroup);
    }
    else
    {
        // add to current group
        curGroup.endDate = s.Date;
    }
}
```

You can do this with Linq using a trick that groups the items by the date minus the index to group consecutive items:

```
samples.OrderBy(s => s.content)   
       .ThenBy(s => s.Date)
       // select each item with its index
       .Select ((s, i) => new {sample = s, index = i})  
       // group by date miuns index to group consecutive items
       .GroupBy(si => new {date = si.sample.Date.AddDays(-si.index), content = si.sample.content})  
       // get the min, max, and content of each group
       .Select(g => new sampleWithIntervals() {
                        startDate = g.Min(s => s.sample.Date), 
                        endDate = g.Max(s => s.sample.Date), 
                        content = g.First().sample.content
                        })
```

Comment: This will not work when there are two samples with different content for the same date. It will create more intervals.

Comment: @RaghaJ - This will work if you first sort `samples` by `content`, then by `Date`

Answer (score 0):

I have this `SplitBy` extension method where you can specify a delimiter predicate with which the collection will be split, just like `string.Split`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                     Func<T, bool> delimiterPredicate,
                                                     bool includeEmptyEntries = false, 
                                                     bool includeSeparator = false)
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (!delimiterPredicate(x))
            l.Add(x);
        else
        {
            if (includeEmptyEntries || l.Count != 0)
            {
                if (includeSeparator)
                    l.Add(x);

                yield return l;
            }

            l = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (l.Count != 0 || includeEmptyEntries)
        yield return l;
}
```

So now splitting is easy if you can specify a consecutive streak delimiter. For that you can order the collection and zip with adjacent items, so now the difference in dates in the two resultant columns can act as delimiter.

```
var ordered = samples.OrderBy(x => x.content).ThenBy(x => x.Date).ToArray();
var result = ordered.Zip(ordered.Skip(1).Append(new sample()), (start, end) => new { start, end })
                    .SplitBy(x => x.end.Date - x.start.Date != TimeSpan.FromDays(1), true, true)
                    .Select(x => x.Select(p => p.start).ToArray())
                    .Where(x => x.Any())
                    .Select(x => new sampleWithIntervals
                    {
                        content = x.First().content,
                        startDate = x.First().Date,
                        endDate = x.Last().Date
                    });
```

`new sample()` is a dummy instance used to get the `Zip` correctly. The `Append` method is to append items to a `IEnumerable<>` sequence, and it goes like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return source.Concat(items);
}
```

**Note:** this doesn't preserve the initial order. If you want the original order, select the index initially and form an anonymous class right away (`Select((x, i) => new { x, i })`) and at the last stage sort on the basis of index before selecting appropriate type.