# Getting grouped date range using linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this data that I have to group by price , and check the range and continouity of data

```
date            price
2014-01-01  10
2014-01-02  10
2014-01-03  10
2014-01-05  20
2014-01-07  30
2014-01-08  40
2014-01-09  50
2014-01-10  30
```

and the output should look like this

```
2014-01-01  2014-01-03  10
2014-01-05  2014-01-05  20
2014-01-07  2014-01-07  30
2014-01-08  2014-01-08  40
2014-01-09  2014-01-09  50
2014-01-10  2014-01-10  30
```

I tried so far

```
 var result = list
                .OrderBy(a => a.Date)
                .GroupBy(a => a.Price)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    DateMax = x.Max(a => a.Date),
                    DateMin = x.Min(a => a.Date),
                    Count = x.Count()
                })
                .ToList()
                .Where(a => a.DateMax.Subtract(a.DateMin).Days == a.Count)
                .ToList();
```

I am not really sure this takes care of continuous dates. All dates are unique!

Comment: So if the price changes one day and two days later  its again the old one you want to get two groups with the same price since there is a different price between both dates?

Comment: I am not really sure this takes care of continuous dates. All dates are unique. What do you mean by this?

Comment: You can remove the `OrderBy` and the first `ToList` without changing any functionality.

Comment: Why `ToList()` twice? and am not sure about this `a.DateMax.Subtract(a.DateMin).Days == a.Count`

Comment: I think you need to provide some better examples.  What should happen if there are non-contiguous dates that share a price, what should happen?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That appears to be there to ensure that the group didn't "skip" any days.  If the number of days equals the different from the min to the max then there is an item in the group for every day.

Comment: @Servy if there are non-contiguous dates that share a same price, then they belong to a different date group. It is important that date group does not contain dates with different price.

Comment: @Servy I do not want to have 2014-01-07 - 2014-01-10  30

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Combining consecutive dates into ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433189/combining-consecutive-dates-into-ranges). Asked a few hours ago!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So first of we'll use a helper method to group consecutive items.  It'll take a function that will be given the "previous" and "current" item, and it will then determine if that item should be in the current group, or should start a new one.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                list.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
            }

            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Now we're able to use that method to group the items and then select out the information that we need:

```
var query = data.OrderBy(item => item.Date)
                .GroupWhile((previous, current) => 
                    previous.Date.AddDays(1) == current.Date
                    && previous.Price == current.Price)
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    DateMin = group.First().Date,
                    DateMax = group.Last().Date,
                    Count = group.Count(),
                    Price = group.First().Price,
                });
```

Comment: I'd always wondered how to do a GroupWhile in an efficient and generic enough way, Servy you are too good.

Comment: May I change the code of the middle of the extention method with `if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
                    }

                    list.Add(iterator.Current);
                    previous = iterator.Current;` This way there is only an if. it's one less line of code but just more readable, imo. Im submiting the edit. Just roll it back if you don't like

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Servy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452273/659190), which I find more elegant and obviously much more resuable,

You could do something more bespoke in one sweep (after ordering.)

```
 public class ContiguousValuePeriod<TValue>
 {
     private readonly DateTime start;
     private readonly DateTime end;
     private readonly TValue value;

     public ContiguousValuePeriod(
             DateTime start,
             DateTime end,
             TValue value)
     {
         this.start = start;
         this.end = end;
         this.value = value;
     }

     public DateTime Start { get { return this.start; } }
     public DateTime End { get { return this.start; } }
     public TValue Value { get { return this.value; } }
 }

 public IEnumerable<ContiguousValuePeriod<TValue>>
                     GetContiguousValuePeriods<TValue, TItem>(
         this IEnumerable<TItem> source,
         Func<TItem, DateTime> dateSelector,
         Func<TItem, TValue> valueSelector)
 {
     using (var iterator = source
             .OrderBy(t => valueSelector(t))
             .ThenBy(t => dateSelector(t))
             .GetEnumerator())
     {
         if (!iterator.MoveNext())
         {
             yield break;
         }

         var periodValue = valueSelector(iterator.Current); 
         var periodStart = dateSelector(iterator.Current);
         var periodLast = periodStart;
         var hasTail = false;

         while (iterator.MoveNext())
         {
              var thisValue = valueSelector(iterator.Current);
              var thisDate = dateSelector(iterator.Current);

              if (!thisValue.Equals(periodValue)  ||
                   thisDate.Subtract(periodLast).TotalDays > 1.0)
              {
                  // Period change
                  yield return new ContiguousValuePeriod(
                      periodStart,
                      periodLast,
                      periodValue);
                  periodStart = thisDate;
                  periodValue = thisValue;
                  hasTail = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  hasTail = true;
              }

              periodLast = thisDate;
          }
      }

      if (hasTail)
      {
          yield return new ContiguousValuePeriod(
                      periodStart,
                      periodLast,
                      periodValue);
      }
  }
```

which you use like,

```
var result = yourList.GetContiguousValuePeriods(
    a => a.Date,
    a => a.Price);
```