# linq datatable find range of value occuring

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable like so:

```
          Id Name State
          1  xx   CA 
          2  xx   NY
          3  xx   NY
          4  xx   NY
          5  xx   NY
          6  xx   CA
          7  xx   CA
          8  xx   NY
          9  xx   NY
```

I wanted to know if there is a linq statement i can create where I get back the range of values (start and end) of in this case a state. 
For Example Linq query = where(state == "NY") and return the occurence of 2,5 and 7,9

Comment: You need to earn the basics of LINQ.

Comment: did you just delete what everyone else posted to tell me that

Comment: You have commented (and deleted your comment) my answer with: "im sorry but instead of using the id is possible to use the row index of the datatable". I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Check out this solution... You could use it here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19434439/1693085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this extension which groups consecutive elements:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupAdjacent(r => r.Field<string>("State"))
    .Where(g => g.Key == "NY")
    .Select(g => new{ Min=g.Min(r => r.Field<int>("Id")), Max=g.Max(r => r.Field<int>("Id")) })
    .ToList();

foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine("Min={0} Max={1}", x.Min, x.Max);   
// Min=2 Max=5
// Min=8 Max=9
```

Here is the extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    TKey last = default(TKey);
    bool haveLast = false;
    List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (TSource s in source)
    {
        TKey k = keySelector(s);
        if (haveLast)
        {
            if (!k.Equals(last))
            {
                yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
                list = new List<TSource>();
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(s);
            last = k;
            haveLast = true;
        }
    }
    if (haveLast)
        yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
}

public class GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    private List<TSource> GroupList { get; set; }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TSource> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var s in GroupList)
            yield return s;
    }
    public GroupOfAdjacent(List<TSource> source, TKey key)
    {
        GroupList = source;
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: "im sorry but instead of using the id is possible to use the row index of the datatable"

Yes, you can use the overload of `Select` that projects the index:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((r, index) => new{ Row=r, Index=index })
    .GroupAdjacent(x => x.Row.Field<string>("State"))
    .Where(g => g.Key=="NY")
    .Select(g => new{ Min=g.Min(x => x.Index), Max=g.Max(x => x.Index) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It will return only `2, 9` for `NY`. Not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434439/1693085), I came up with this bit of code that should do the trick for you:

**NOTE** For the sake of time, I created a list of a class with 3 properties, but to pull it from a DataTable should be near-identical....

```
var newlist1 = (MyList.Where(li => li.State == "NY")
               .OrderBy(li => li.Id)
               .Select((li, idx) => new {itm = li, val = li.Id - idx})
               .GroupBy(nw => nw.val)
               .Select(g => new { Min = g.Min(nw => nw.itm.Id), 
                                  Max = g.Max(nw => nw.itm.Id)})
                ).ToList();
```

The part that makes this work is the `val` in the `GroupBy` clause after ordering the results - In effect, since the data is ordered and we're subtracting the index of each element in the ordered list from the id - all elements that are sequential will get the same `val`, so will therefore fall into the same group. All you need to do then is, for each group, get the max `id` and the min `id` and you're done.

Hope this gives you what you're looking for.